# Synapse notebook incorrect detects column type

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2, spark-notebook

I'm import data from a csv into a parquet file using a Synapse Notebook. The code types the Zip Code field as an INT, losing the preceding 0(s) on many Zip Codes.  My question is how can I force a column to be typed as a string?  Here is the code that I'm using to read and write with.  Code is very generic currently and I'd like to maintain that if possible.

```
SourceFilePath = 'abfss://datalake@blobstorageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/SourceDir/SourceFileName.csv'
dfb = spark.read.load(SourceFilePath,format='csv',header = True).cache()
DestinationPath = 'abfss://datalake@blobstorageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/DestinationUnknown/'
dfB.write \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .parquet(DestinationPath)
```

I'm not keen on solving for this in a Synapse Serverless view on the destination. As I can't force people to use the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **option** method to define the schema of the CSV file. Here is an example of how to specify the schema of the CSV file and force the Zip Code column to be typed as a string:

**Input data:**

| Zip code | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 004 | city1 | country1 |
| 002 | city2 | country2 |

**Code:**

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("Zip Code", StringType(), True),
    StructField("city", StringType(), True),
    StructField("country", StringType(), True)
])

SourceFilePath = 'abfss://csv@dlg2aswin.dfs.core.windows.net/AAPL.txt'
dfb = spark.read \
    .option("header", True) \
    .option("inferSchema", False) \
    .schema(schema) \
    .csv(SourceFilePath) \
    .cache()
#dfb.show()
DestinationPath = 'abfss://csv@dlg2aswin.dfs.core.windows.net/AAPLdest/'
dfb.write \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .parquet(DestinationPath)
```

[image]

In this code, we created a schema that insists that the Zip Code column to be entered as a string. The CSV file's schema is then specified using the option method, and the Zip Code column is displayed as string input only.

Comment: Current code processes 500+ files with no schema.  If I understand your approach, I'd have to fully define the schema for all 500 file (and keep up with schema drift of adding new columns, deleting old columns, and name changes) Whereas my current solution of letting the schema being inferred works for almost all situations with no manual coding.  What I'm looking for is a way to only override a column with a header of ZipCode to force it to be a String.